# how to replace several NA values in columns of a data frame with the mean of the values of the columns

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, mean, na

I have a df from a psychology inventory answers. There are some NA values that I want to change with the mean of the column values. I have tried two methods
the first is create a function that ill use later with a sapply:

```
nar <- function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <<- round(mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))}
```

but when I proved the function, it did not work. However this code actually works with a single column:

```
x[is.na(x)] <<- round(mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
```

so I found that i could do also a ifelse, that also works with one column but i dont know how to apply it to all the columns (i tried sapply and apply and it didn't work). However i dont know what to put as NO argument in the ifelse function. I just want it to do nothing but i don't know how to do that.

```
ifelse(is.na(dfv[,col]) == TRUE, dfv[,col][is.na(dfv[,col])] <- round(mean(dfv[,col], na.rm = TRUE)), help)
```

So may question is: How can I replace NA values with the mean of the column values where that NA value is in a whole data frame automatically?

I'll appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `<<-`. Very rarely (never) it is useful. Try using it this way :

```
nar <- function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- round(mean(x, na.rm = TRUE));x}
dfv[,col] <- sapply(dfv[,col], nar)
```

Comment: it worked. Thanks you a lot! can you explain me why the x goes at the end after the ; ? if you can of course